# Line width Manim

Tags: python, animation, manim

Is there any way to increase the width of the specific line on animation?

I have tried to change `DEFAULT_STROKE_WIDTH` in `constants.py`  and set `stroke_width` in `CONFIG` equal to some number but it did not work.

Here is the part of my code. My line is just a path along a tuple of points.

```
        path = VMobject()
        path.set_points_smoothly([*[coord(x,y) for x,y in self.tuples]])
        path.set_color(RED)
```

Any suggestions?

UPD

Setting `DEFAULT_STROKE_WIDTH` in `constants.py` works, but it is not surprising that it changes width of ALL lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parameter `stroke_width` could be used.

For example:

`rect = Rectangle(height=1, width=1, stroke_width=1)`

P.S. I got an answer after some playing with object parameters.